# How to scroll horizontal listview by both direction left to right and right left in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```dart
ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: smartAccessoriesList.length,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return SmartAccessories(
                        title: smartAccessoriesList[index].title,
                        imgPath: smartAccessoriesList[index].imgPath,
                        onPress: () {},
                      );
                    },
                  ),
```

Comment: Can you explain a  little more about the scroll behavior?

Comment: try to remove itemCount for infinite loop, or anything you can find in https://pub.dev/packages?q=infinite+list

Comment: I want to scroll horizontal  list  bi-directional.